# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error on server not locally

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2013, web-config, web-hosting

am uploading my website on a webshared hosting server i use visual studio published the website using the file system setting then uploaded the files using FTP when i try to open any of my pages i get an error http error 500.19 i looked around found that this error is usually caused by webconfig malfunction so i reuploaded webcondig changed connection string and tryed even reuploading the whole website but nothing worked i use mssql database when i looked around i found solutions like adding this  to the webconfig but nothing actually made an impact this is a link of my website http://jamalkawar-001-site1.smarterasp.net/user%20pages/loggin.aspx which have the error any suggestions of how can i fix this ?!
on visual studio debuger everything works fine

[image: the error page]

Comment: How about simply googling your error? It says "Cannot read configuration file".

Comment: i saw that much the same webconfig file was working a week ago and now doesnt work it worked localy and i tryed replacing it checking connection string as put in the question and none of the answer i found had any affect thats why i asked the question already did my research

Comment: Your error code is: "0x80070003" for that web.config, so all ready the same question here...

Comment: if you see on your error page here `\\?\h:\root\home\jamalkawar-001\www\site1\userpages\web.config` is the same issue....